Conflict ExoPlayer's versions after integration of Flutter Zoom SDK in Flutter app
In my Flutter project, I am using ExoPlayer with version com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.17.1 and now I want to integrate Flutter Zoom SDK and this SDK is using com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.12.3 version so after integration of this SDK getting error like Duplicate class found modules exoplayer so now I tried workaround like below that mentioned on this open issue,
fixed it with this. app>>build.gradle

implementation('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.14.1'){
exclude group: 'androidx.core' , module : 'core'
exclude group: 'androidx.media' , module : 'media'
}

So Now I got error: attribute fastforward_increment (aka com.app.fitlife:fastforward_increment) not found. can you please provide suggestion how I can use both exoplayer's version in single project or another alternative that we should do it.
I tried this already : Github issue
